# GitLab CI: iOS project issue (permission denied)

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, realm, gitlab, cocoapods

Trying GitLab CI for my iOS project, I follow [this](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-set-up-gitlab-continuous-integration-for-ios-projects-without-a-hustle-53c2b642c90f), [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html) and [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html) tutorial.

Two questions:

1. What is wrong with my gitlab-runner (with "shell" registration) since GitLab CI throws the following error:

```rb
Running with gitlab-runner 11.9.0 (692ae235)
  on MyApp runner with shell DsaBC-oQ
Using Shell executor...
Running on MyComputer.network.provider...
mkdir: /Users/myusername/builds/DsaBC-oQ/0/username/myproj.tmp: Permission denied
mkdir: /Users/myusername/builds/DsaBC-oQ/0/username/myproj.tmp: Permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

2. Some people say to use "sudo" for the gitlab-runner registration. But then I would need "docker". But it seems that "docker" can't be used for an iOS project in GitLab (but only "shell" registration). Is this true ? (if no, how does the gitlab-runner registration cmd look like exactly for a docker registration ??). Does "docker" work for an iOS-project at all using GitLab ??

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```rb
stages:
  - unit_tests

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

unit_tests:
  dependencies: []
  stage: unit_tests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane tests
  tags:
    - ios
```

I tried to register the gitlab-runner as follows:

```rb
gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token "TOKENABCDEF" \
  --description "MyApp runner with shell" \
  --tag-list ios \
  --executor "shell"
```

The "shell" trial make Gitlab-CI show the above mentioned error (i.e. `permission denied`)

And I also tried to register the gitlab-runner with docker:

```rb
gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token "TOKENABCEDF" \
  --description "MyApp runner with docker and ruby-2.6” \
  --tag-list ios \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image ruby:2.6
```

But the "docker" trial made the GitLab-CI show another error (i.e. `[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root`) as explained in more detail [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393974/gitlab-ci-with-docker-fastlane-and-cocoapods-not-working?noredirect=1#comment97518628_55393974)

Any idea on how to make this GitLab-CI for an iOS-project finally work properly at all ?? Thanks for any hint. (after 3 days of trials I am more than desperate for this to work)...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the "permission denied" error on my GitLab Pipeline had nothing to do with GitLab itself - but was due to a Ruby version mismatch on my Mac that I connected with the gitlab-runner.

I was able to update my Ruby version [with the help of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25716203/3826232) (i.e. using `chruby`). There are other possibilities out there on how to update Ruby on your Mac. It is important to understand that GitLab requires your Mac to have a stable Ruby environment.

As a side-note: [Here is the best tutorial on how to set up GitLab CI for an iOS-project](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/03/06/ios-publishing-with-gitlab-and-fastlane/#comment-4401018524) that I have found.